# Activate a VPN on iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, networking

is there a way to activate an existing VPN on the iPhone from a native program? The VPN connection is configured in Settings, but requires a password; both flashing a system password prompt and providing a password parameter (from my own UI) would be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looking for the exact same thing, private API would be ok, no store required. But can't find anything. Ever figured this out?

Comment: @V1ru8: no. Found two alternatives. First, APN. That's where your company makes a contract with AT&T so that there's a VPN channel between AT&T's network and your corporate one, available only to the company-issued phones. This way, the corporate phones are on the corporate network without knowing it. No idea what's the price, I just know that's an option. The second alternative - and that's the way we went - is to meet with the security people, negotiate a public Web server and tunnel all access to corporate data through services on it.

Comment: What I've found so far are some c functions in the SystemConfiguration.framework like VPNConfigurationConnectionStart etc. But it would be pretty expensive to get all the method signatures and how they work. But with them I think it would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There is no public API for that.