# ios programmatically activating existing VPN connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, vpn

Has this been changed yet. Is there a way to do this?

I already have en existing VPN connection configured (password promted on activate of connection not saved) i want to activate this connection from my app.

Existing topic from 2010 states no, but that was 3 years ago:

[Activate a VPN on iPhone programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195612/activate-a-vpn-on-iphone-programmatically)

Comment: Nope, still not possible to change any generic system settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is still no public API to turn it on.

There were VPN on demand for some time. I believe Apple got sued and they deprecated it.

iOS 7 introduces new thingy related to VPN. Since, it's still under NDA. Please go to https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/‎ and check out Managing Mobile Devices. This new functionality still can't be triggered by app, but it may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 delivers per-app VPN, but it must be supported by your backend infrastructure and your devices must be under mobile device management.  Take a look at this post: [iOS 7 programatically per app VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961407/ios-7-programatically-per-app-vpn/19547175#19547175)